# msinfo command line export only running tasks

Tags: msinfo32

I want from command line to run msinfo32 and get to a text file ONLY the running tasks of the system. For example I run the command :

msinfo32 /report .\nfo.txt /categories-all+SWEnvRunningTasks

```
msinfo32 /report .\nfo.txt /category +SWEnvRunningTasks
```

....but it exports many other information.
 Can someone write the correct command syntax? Thanks

I 'm running on Windows 7 64Bit but I think it doesn't matter. I will accept an answer for any system.
  I think it's another "Microsoft" bug. There is no such functionality that Microsft declares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use Powershell rather than msinfo32, this is significantly easier and a lot quicker: `powershell Get-Process`. This runs quickly and can easily be piped to a file, e.g. `powershell Get-Process > .\nfo.txt`. This should work on any version of Windows which supports Powershell 2.0 or later, I believe.

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176855.aspx for complete documentation of the `Get-Process` cmdlet. There are a lot of options you can use to limit the columns the cmdlet outputs, so that you don't have to parse a ton of extra columns.

Comment: ok I will accept the answer as with powershell I can do it. But I realize that msinfo32 certainly has a problem. Anyway thanks for your time & reply.